# Select truncated string from Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, casting, varchar

I have some large `varchar` values in Postgres that I want to SELECT and move somewhere else. The place they are going to uses `VARCHAR(4095)` so I only need at most 4095 bytes (I think that's bytes) and some of these varchars are quite big, so a performance optimization would be to SELECT a truncated version of them.

How can I do that?
Something like:

```
SELECT TRUNCATED(my_val, 4095) ...
```

I don't think it's a character length though, it needs to be a byte length?

Comment: Is this question answered properly?

Answer (score 47):

The `n` in `varchar(n)` is the number of characters, not bytes. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

> SQL defines two primary character types: `character varying(n)` and
> `character(n)`, where *`n`* is a positive integer. Both of these types can
> store strings up to *`n`* **characters (not bytes)** in length.

Bold emphasis mine.

Use [`left()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to "truncate" a string to a given number of characters:

```
SELECT left(my_val, 4095);
```

Or [cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

```
SELECT my_val::varchar(4095);
```

[The manual once more:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

> If one explicitly casts a value to `character varying(n)` or
> `character(n)`, then an over-length value will be truncated to *`n`*
> characters without raising an error. (This too is required by the SQL standard.)

The former returns `text` and is typically preferable - unless you expressly need the type `varchar(4095)`. The result will be coerced to `text` in most contexts anyway.